# Checking for case insensitive parameters

Tags: flash, actionscript

in flash/actionscript you can provide flashvars to the movie.

in actionscript you can access them like this:

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
```

then i can check a parameter like this:

```
if (paramObj["somekey"] == someValue)
{
}
```

now i want to make this check case-insensitive. so that it matches SomeKey or soMekEY, etc.

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem a few years ago when I was working with ColdFusion and Flash, because ColdFusion is case insensitive whereas AS3 is not.

So here's what I did to get around that problem.

```
public class ObjectUtil {

    public static function getParameter(obj:Object, name:String):Object {
        if(obj==null || name="" || name=="undefined") {
            return null;
        }

        for (var key:String in obj) {
            if(key.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()) {
                return obj[key]
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Now that I see the entire post thread, I notice that @vulkanino does the same thing, although his code returns strings only and is confined to arguments of the String type.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a public (static) method that gets the parameters, given the param name, that converts the param name to lower case:

```
class Utility
{
    public static GetParam(name:String): String
    {
        if ( paramObj == null )
            paramObj = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;

        var lowerCasedName:String  = name.toLowerCase();
        for (keyStr in paramObj) 
        {
           if ( keyStr.toLowerCase() == lowerCasedName ) 
               return String(paramObj[keyStr]);
        }
        return null;
    }

    static var paramObj:Object = null;
}
```

You have no other option than scanning all the keys in the parameter object.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is, that the parameter in the paramObj might be in any case, and this will only match lowercase names.